# Invoke Meteor method only on the client

Tags: meteor

Is there any way to tell `Meteor.call` or `Meteor.apply` to only run the client side stub and not invoke the server method?

Let's say we have the todo list example. Maybe we want to show anonymous (not logged in) users some default tasks:

> - Try to check a task
> - Rename one
> - Add your own
> - Create account

Users logged in should see their tasks and we do not want to implement all the functionality twice (once for registered and once for anonymous users).

If this is implemented the normal way, Meteor will push the changes to all connected clients, meaning all anonymous users will share the same tasks and see edits of others in real time.

Adding own tasks for each anonymous user would fill the database with useless things.

So I am looking for a way to only run the methods on the client side `if (!Meteor.user())`.

Comment: why make it so complicated, why not just create the function you want and call it directly? You can still use the same function inside the method stub for consistency.

Comment: What do you mean? The interface renders the Tasks collection. The Tasks collection is updated on the server and pushed down to the client. What do you mean with "create the function […] and call it directly"? Which function would I create? How to call it directly?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this:

**Just add those todos in the database (anyways).**

This is the simplest way to do it, because you won't add any additional logic to your app (except adding data to your app when an anonymous logs into your app).

You said it would "fill the database with useless things", but does it really matter? The complete works of Shakespeare weights roughly 5MB, you probably won't have any issue with this.

If you go this way, you may want to add an anonymous account system, to reference which user owns which items. I would recommend the [artwells:accounts-guest](https://atmospherejs.com/artwells/accounts-guest) package, but there are some other ones.

**Use a client-only collection.**

```
DummyTodos = new Mongo.Collection('dummy-todos');
```

You want to make sure this code is only ran on the client side, so either:

- surround it with `if(Meteor.isClient)`;
- or put it in a file in the `/your-root-project/client` folder.

But then you will have to add more logic in all places where you deal with todos:

```
    Meteor.methods({
      'todo.setChecked'(todoId, isChecked) {
        check(todoId, String);
        check(isChecked, Boolean);
            var todo = Todos.findOne(todoId);
            var todoClass = Todos;

            if(!todo && Meteor.isClient){
                todo = DummyTodos.findOne(todoId);
                todoClass = DummyTodos
            }

            if(todo) {
                todoClass.update(todoId, { $set: { checked: isChecked } });
            } else if(Meteor.isClient){
                // On the server side, you don't know whether something went wrong, or it was just a local todo
                // So you're losing some error handling here, which isn't good

                // You can still deal with this on the client-side, maybe you want to:
                throw "No todo with id " + todoId;
                // or just
                return;
                // But the server will fail silently, so you're losing error handling
            }

      },
    });
```

You can see that there's quite more logic, you could wrap it up in a function, like:

```
    var getTodoOrDummyTodo: function(todoId) {
        var todo = Todos.findOne(todoId);

        if(!todo && Meteor.isClient){
            todo = DummyTodos.findOne(todoId);
        }

        // I return some todo, but I don't know where it comes from
        if(todo)
            return todo;
        else
            throw "Well, something wrong happened but I'm not sure what"
    }
```

But you see there are other issues (you don't know where the todo comes from, you have no control on the server-side,...). You could also flag the todos (add an "isDummy" field, like:

```
    Meteor.methods({
      'todo.setChecked'(todoId, isChecked) {
```

But again, this means you'll have to look at this flag everywhere. It's not future proof

**Use plain javascript objects and functions**

I think this is what @christian-fritz suggested in the comments to your question. You could use plain javascript objects, and merge them with you collection:

```
    var dummyTodos = [
        {text: "Hello", checked: true},
        {text: "Bye", checked: false}
    ]

    var todos = Todos.find();
    if(todos.count() < 1){
        return dummyTodos;
    } else {
        return todos;
    }
```

In your Meteor method you could send the todo object directly, check if there's an _id field, and update it accordingly, like this (simplified):

```
    Meteor.methods({
      'todo.setChecked'(todoObject, isChecked) {
        // Do the checks
        if(todoObject._id){
            Todos.update(todoObject._id, { $set: { checked: isChecked } });
        } else {
            todoObject.checked = isChecked;
        }
```

But then you would lose the reactivity of the collection and the template (which you can implement yourself, using [Tracker Dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_dependency), but again, this isn't the simplest way).

**TL;DR**: Those examples show why it's a bad idea to have two different data stores for a similar object, especially if they have different APIs, and you can't create a "mock" of the collection that would be similar to the mongo collection object. If the "todos" were not an important object in your app, you could use an alternative, like the ones I've shown, but here that will probaly make 10% more code in you whole app, if not more. So use server-side collection.